# Python3.0 Mayavi rotating cube glyph

Tags: mayavi

Using mayavi points3d and using cube to plot the image. Is there a way to rotate a cube to certain orientation during the plot?

```
mlab.figure(2)
mlab.points3d(GrainsFile[:,6],GrainsFile[:,7],GrainsFile[:,8],GrainsFile[:,11])
```

[image: mayavi cube plot]

Comment: Rotate each cube on its center? a single cube on its center? all cubes on the centroid?

Comment: rotate each cube on its center with an individual rotation matrix. Is there a way to prescribe a rotation for glyph in mayavi ?

Answer (score 2):

I had to search the Mayavi code for this one. Once I found that those cube are a `GlyphSource`, I found some transformation operation in one of its methods:

```
import numpy
from mayavi import mlab

def test_points3d():
    t = numpy.linspace(0, 4 * numpy.pi, 20)

    x = numpy.sin(2 * t)
    y = numpy.cos(t)
    z = numpy.cos(2 * t)
    s = 2 + numpy.sin(t)

    points = mlab.points3d(x, y, z, s, colormap="viridis", scale_factor=.25,
    mode='cube')
    # rotate 45° on Z
    points.glyph.glyph_source._trfm.transform.rotate_z(45)
test_points3d()
```

[image: points3d example rotated 45° on Z]

Comment: Thanks Felipe. This was very helpful.

Comment: if I have x, y, z, s as list,  can I pass array for angles instead of (45) in your code for individual cubes ?

Comment: I don't think you can with `points3d()`, since the code is written on the premise that you use a single GlyphSource object (definition). I'd recommend experimenting with the `quiver3d()` until you get satisfying results (I don't think you can get _exactly_ what you request for, though)

Comment: Thanks Felipe. Ya I couldn't find it in the documentation. May be i should think of something else.